# React Native render error (element type is invalid)

Tags: react-native

Whenever i load the simulator for this react native project, I am getting this specific error

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `LoginPage`.

This error is located at:
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AnimatedComponent)
    in AnimatedComponent
    in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by TouchableOpacity)
    in TouchableOpacity (created by TouchableOpacity)
    in TouchableOpacity (created by LoginPage)
    in RCTSafeAreaView (created by LoginPage)
    in LoginPage (created by SceneView)
    in StaticContainer
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by SceneView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by DebugContainer)
    in DebugContainer (created by MaybeNestedStack)
    in MaybeNestedStack (created by SceneView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by SceneView)
    in RNSScreen (created by AnimatedComponent)
    in AnimatedComponent
    in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by InnerScreen)
    in Suspender (created by Freeze)
    in Suspense (created by Freeze)
    in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
    in DelayedFreeze (created by InnerScreen)
    in InnerScreen (created by Screen)
    in Screen (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by NativeStackViewInner)
    in Suspender (created by Freeze)
    in Suspense (created by Freeze)
    in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
    in DelayedFreeze (created by ScreenStack)
    in RNSScreenStack (created by ScreenStack)
    in ScreenStack (created by NativeStackViewInner)
    in NativeStackViewInner (created by NativeStackView)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
    in SafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by NativeStackView)
    in NativeStackView (created by NativeStackNavigator)
    in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
    in NavigationContent
    in Unknown (created by NativeStackNavigator)
    in NativeStackNavigator (created by App)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator
    in BaseNavigationContainer
    in ThemeProvider
    in NavigationContainerInner (created by App)
    in App
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in MedAlertRN(RootComponent), js engine: hermes
```

After hours of googling, this error seems to be linked to the way components are exported/imported. However, I have followed the convention of emitting {} in imports when using default export and vice versa (see code snippets). Does anyone have any solutions to this? Would appreciate all the help! Thank you!

Just for reference, I have included two code snippets below.

App.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {useState, useEffect, useRef} from 'react';
import {DocumentReference} from 'firebase/firestore';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import HomeScreen from './pages/HomeScreen';
import LoginPage from './pages/LoginPage';
import SignUpHomePage from './pages/SignUpHomePage';
import SignUpDetailsPage from './pages/SignUpDetailsPage';
import AddMedicationType from './pages/AddMedicationType';
import AddMedicationDetails from './pages/AddMedicationDetails';
import AddMedicationSchedule from './pages/AddMedicationSchedule';
import MenuPage from './pages/MenuPage';
import UpdateAccountPage from './pages/UpdateAccountPage';
import EditMedicationDetails from './pages/EditMedicationDetails';
import EditMedicationSchedule from './pages/EditMedicationSchedule';
import ViewMedicationPage from './pages/ViewMedicationPage';
import {MedicationItem, ScheduledItem, UserInformation} from './utils/types';
import {doc, getDoc, updateDoc} from 'firebase/firestore';
import {firestorage} from './firebaseConfig';
import {userDataConverter} from './converters/userDataConverter';
import {medDataConverter} from './converters/medDataConverter';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
export default function App(): JSX.Element {
  const [userInformation, setUserInformation] = useState<UserInformation>({
    Name: '',
    Gender: '',
    DateOfBirth: '',
    EmailAddress: '',
    PhoneNumber: '',
    ProfilePicture: '',
  });
  const [allMedicationItems, setAllMedicationItems] = useState<
    MedicationItem[]
  >([]);
  const [scheduledItems, setScheduledItems] = useState<ScheduledItem[]>([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState('');
  const [isSignUpComplete, setIsSignUpComplete] = useState(false);
  const medInfoRef = useRef<DocumentReference>();
  const userInfoRef = useRef<DocumentReference>();
  const [expoPushToken, setExpoPushToken] = useState('');
  const [notification, setNotification] = useState(false);

  /** Auxiliary functions */

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" options={{headerShown: false}}>
          {props => <LoginPage {...props} onLogin={handleLogin} />}
        </Stack.Screen>
        <Stack.Screen name="Sign Up Home" options={{headerShown: false}}>
          {props => <SignUpHomePage {...props} onSignUp={handleSignUp} />}
        </Stack.Screen>
        <Stack.Screen name="Sign Up Details" options={{headerShown: false}}>
          {props => (
            <SignUpDetailsPage
              {...props}
              setIsSignUpComplete={setIsSignUpComplete}
            />
          )}
        </Stack.Screen>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" options={{headerShown: false}}>
          {props => (
            <HomeScreen
              {...props}
              scheduledItems={scheduledItems}
              setAcknowledged={setAcknowledged}
              userName={userInformation.Name}
            />
          )}
        </Stack.Screen>
        <Stack.Screen name="Add Medication Type" options={{headerShown: false}}>
          {props => <AddMedicationType {...props} />}
        </Stack.Screen>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Add Medication Details"
          options={{headerShown: false}}>
          {props => <AddMedicationDetails {...props} />}
        </Stack.Screen>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Add Medication Schedule"
          options={{headerShown: false}}>
          {props => (
            <AddMedicationSchedule {...props} addMedication={addMedication} />
          )}
        </Stack.Screen>
        <Stack.Screen name="Profile Page" options={{headerShown: false}}>
          {props => <MenuPage {...props} userInformation={userInformation} />}
        </Stack.Screen>
        <Stack.Screen name="Update Account" options={{headerShown: false}}>
          {props => (
            <UpdateAccountPage
              {...props}
              userInformation={userInformation}
              updateUserInformation={updateUserInformation}
            />
          )}
        </Stack.Screen>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Edit Medication Details"
          options={{headerShown: false}}>
          {props => (
            <EditMedicationDetails
              {...props}
              allMedicationItems={allMedicationItems}
              deleteMedicationFromList={deleteMedicationFromList}
            />
          )}
        </Stack.Screen>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Edit Medication Schedule"
          options={{headerShown: false}}>
          {props => (
            <EditMedicationSchedule
              {...props}
              allMedicationItems={allMedicationItems}
              setEdit={setEdit}
            />
          )}
        </Stack.Screen>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="View All Medications"
          options={{headerShown: false}}>
          {props => (
            <ViewMedicationPage
              {...props}
              allMedicationItems={allMedicationItems}
            />
          )}
        </Stack.Screen>
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

LoginPage.jsx

```
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  StatusBar,
} from 'react-native';
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {LinearGradient} from 'react-native-linear-gradient';
import {signIn, auth} from '../Auth';
import {onAuthStateChanged} from 'firebase/auth';
import React from 'react';

export default function LoginPage({navigation, onLogin}) {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [showPassword, setShowPassword] = useState(false);
  const togglePasswordVisibility = () => {
    setShowPassword(!showPassword);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, user => {
      if (user) {
        // User is signed in
        navigation.navigate('Home');
      }
    });

    return () => unsubscribe(); // Clean up the auth state listener
  }, []);

  const handleLogin = async () => {
    try {
      const [success, id] = await signIn(email, password);
      if (success) {
        onLogin(id);
        navigation.navigate('Home');
      } else {
        alert('Login failed');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
      <Text style={styles.title}>Welcome!</Text>
      <View style={styles.inputItem}>
        <Text style={styles.inputTitle}>Email</Text>
        <View style={styles.inputBox}>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.inputText}
            value={email}
            placeholder="Email"
            onChangeText={text => setEmail(text)}></TextInput>
        </View>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.inputItem}>
        <Text style={styles.inputTitle}>Password</Text>
        <View style={styles.inputBox}>
          <TextInput
            style={{flex: 8}}
            value={password}
            secureTextEntry={!showPassword}
            placeholder="Password"
            onChangeText={text => setPassword(text)}></TextInput>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.showButton}
            onPress={togglePasswordVisibility}></TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => handleLogin()}
        style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <LinearGradient colors={['#FFA7AF', '#FF014E']} style={styles.gradient}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Sign In</Text>
        </LinearGradient>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <View
        style={{
          margin: 5,
          flexDirection: 'row',
          alignItems: 'center',
          width: '90%',
        }}>
        <View style={styles.line}></View>
        <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 15, marginHorizontal: 10}}>
          Or
        </Text>
        <View style={styles.line}></View>
      </View>

      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Sign Up Home')}
        style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <LinearGradient colors={['#FFA7AF', '#FF014E']} style={styles.gradient}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Sign Up</Text>
        </LinearGradient>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <View style={styles.emptySection}></View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a good coding practice, you should isolate the problem and not try to change large pieces of code. After you are sure that works, Then you can move on to more complex code.

I leave you the minimal example:

```
<Stack.Screen name="Example" component={ExamplePage} />
```

Then, to pass parameters to this screen while using React navigation

```
navigation.navigate('Example', {firstName: 'Jorge', lastName: 'Perez'});
```

then on a page file:

```
export default function ExamplePage({route}) {
  const {firstName, lastName} = route.params;

  return <Text>Hello, {firstName} {lastName}</Text;
}
```

This is the minimal example, so please before modifying your own code, try to make this work in a sandbox.
Good luck!